# The Systemback not let me select storage directory!! Why?

Tags: restore

How can I solve this problem??

The image shows that my external HD (MarioHD) is disabled!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Correct guntbert.. but it would be nice if accepted the FAT32 and NTFS, because it would just temporaril storage... maybe in future versions! Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please choose a writable Linux filesystem. The NTFS, FAT32 or other non-compatible filesystems are not good.

Comment: Why is FAT32 not good for a backup with systemback?

Comment: Yeap! Tanks kendek

Comment: After saving in my pendrive (to accept the linux format), I can send the files that Sistemback to my external HD with NTFS format?

Comment: No, the NTFS and the FAT32 filesystems are not compatible, because they cannot handle the Linux permissions. If you using a non-compatible filesystem, the restored system does not start. So it would not make sense to create a restore point.

Comment: If I create a restore point in a pendrive (Compatible with Linux) and then save those files on my external HD..  when I need to restore I put the files on the USB stick (compatible with linux) and run the restore again. This will work?